# How to make 2D color tiles for the 2048 game

Tags: haskell

I would like to develop a terminal version of the 2048 game with Haskell. And i'm lost with the Console interface part.

Any tips on which console library to use for making those color tiles ?

Comment: Isn't `ncurses` usually used for terminal related stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vty-ui](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/vty-ui/) should be good for that purpose. It also has a good amount of [documentation](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/vty-ui/manuals/vty-ui-users-manual-1.6.1.pdf) with it. I think it has attributes for setting background and foreground color.

Comment: Which widget should I use ? I took a quick look and found the box type

Comment: Care to show a quick 2 liners to demonstrate how to draw one color tile with numbers in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Sorry, haven't played much with vty-ui. But I think you have to use both horizontal as well as vertical box layout for putting them under grid.